# How in the world could missing a `println()` cause my Swift application to crash?

Tags: swift

I have this in an `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method:

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
    var currentUserCount = self.users?.count
    self.users = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.responseData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>
    println("Connection did finish loading \(self.distance!) distance.")
    println("Users: \(self.users?.count)")
    println("Response Data: \(self.users?)")
    if self.users?.count < 2 {
        // The collection view isn't full, so we'll search further
        self.distance! += 20
        self.fetchUsers()
        println("Reload collection view data")
        self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    if currentUserCount > self.users?.count {
        // There are new cells, so we'll reload the table data
        println("Reload collection view data")
        self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I've noticed if I don't have that `println("Response Data: \(self.users?)")` at line `6` my application immediately crashes with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Am I missing something? How in the world is this possible?

(I'd be happy to give you more of my code if you'd like it.)

The error is at the line `cellImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: currentUsersBase64ImageData)!)!)!` in the following method, by the way.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    var screenWidthDividedWith3 = CGFloat(Int(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width) / 3)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 127 / 255, green: 235 / 255, blue: 127 / 255, alpha: 1)

    var cellLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 85, 116.5, 25))
    cellLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.8)
    cellLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1)
    cellLabel.text = "  " + self.users!["\(indexPath.row)"]!["username"]!
    // ^ I didn't know how to better make a text indentation without subclassing
    cellLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 16)
    println("Looking for data at row: '\(indexPath.row)'")

    var currentUsersBase64ImageData = self.users!["\(indexPath.row)"]!["imageData"]!
    println("<Base64 Image Data>")
    var cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 116.5, 116.5))
    cellImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: currentUsersBase64ImageData)!)!)!

    cell.addSubview(cellImage)
    cell.addSubview(cellLabel)

    return cell
}
```

Not useful, but I'd like to say that I'd tested this ten times. It crashes every single time I don't `println()`, and never when I do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to that statement, the println itself, and the expression inside (self.users).

I'm going to take a wild guess that the users's property getter is doing some sort of initialization, and if you don't do it then, it later on crashes.

Comment: Does that mean that calling it for interpolation in a string initialises it somehow? It's just an instance variable of type `Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>?`. *I* haven't created any getter for it. I have whatever I'm given by default. (I honestly don't know if that means it's being initialised by default.)

Comment: If there's not getter, then I'm wrong. As I said, it was just a wild guess.